# How to catch save record action in NavigationMixin LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, modal, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a pice code:

```
navigateToRecordEditPage(event) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.target.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'edit'
            }
        });
    }
```

This code opens an edit modal. I want to catch when the user clicks 'save' on this modal.
How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, You cannot catch that event, you need to override the edit button for that.

Comment: so after that, I need to override the edit action and write a modal component it cause more work...

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? why do you want to catch a save event?

Comment: because I want to refresh data in component from which I call the method after edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out it is impossible. If u want to do that you need to override standard edit modal.

Comment: For anyone looking for a workaround: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/323996/69889

Answer (score 0):

A long workaround however saves some custom dev is using a platform event and then calling your refresh method in there.
See this article, also has a link to a fix to the original article
[LWC - empApi for publishing and subscribing platform event from Lightning web component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280927/lwc-empapi-for-publishing-and-subscribing-platform-event-from-lightning-web-co)

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.