# Perform Processing After NavigationMixin Modal Dialog Save Clicked

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a fairly standard navigationmixin situation where once a button is clicked I instantiate the New action. The only difference is that I provide an option to redirect to the new record or not. So something like this -

```
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: 'new',
            },
            state: {
                useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST',
            }
        })
```

Poking around I was able to figure out that the navigationLocation state parameter is what is used to set whether the redirect happens or not. Great. That all works.

Now, if we are NOT redirecting like the example above is written, I would like to perform some processing on the page. So in my case I want to refresh a components data when the user clicks "Save" on the popup modal dialog.

How?

I was hoping to be able to use a promise of some kind like the following (this does not work) -

```
    let navLocation = 'RELATED_LIST';

    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: this.selectedObject,
                actionName: 'new',
            },
            state: {
                useRecordTypeCheck: 1,
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
                navigationLocation: navLocation,
            }
    }).then((event) => {
        //if we are NOT redirecting
        if (navLocation === 'RELATED_LIST')
            this.refreshAllListViewData();
    });
```

(Note the promise at the end.)

So, how do I "catch" the Save button being clicked and perform processing after a navigationmixin.navigate modal dialog has been displayed?

Comment: Can you try below steps which were mentioned in (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323944/how-to-refresh-the-component-in-lwc-after-successful-save-of-standard-record-pag)