# Call function on lightning-navigation standard__recordPage edit pop-up close

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

I have a custom lwc that calls an edit pop-up for Event records like this:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: "standard__recordPage",
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: "Event",
            actionName: "edit"
        }
    });
}
```

And everything is working fine but I want to do a refresh of my lwc when the edit pop-up is being closed (no matter if it's due to the cancel or save button)

I've checked the documentation and found nothing related to this topic.

Is this even possible? I don't mind if it's via NavigationMixin.Navigate params with an event listener.

**UPDATE**

I've checked with @wire to the current page reference but it's not working. This is my piece of code:

```
wInitResult;
@wire(CurrentPageReference) refreshedURL(pageRef) {
    console.log('***pageRef', pageRef);
    refreshApex(this.wInitResult);
  }
@wire(initData, { recordID : '$recordId' }) winitData (response){
    console.log('***wire', response);
    this.wInitResult = response;
    if(response.data){
        //do some actions
    }
    else if(response.error){
        //display some errors
    }
}
handleGenerateEditVisitURL(){
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: "standard__recordPage",
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: "Event",
            actionName: "edit"
        }
    });
}
```

But I see the `***pageRef` log only for the first iteration and not also when I open the edit modal. Is there something I'm missing?

Regards,

Comment: This question was already asked here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323944/how-to-refresh-the-component-in-lwc-after-successful-save-of-standard-record-pag. Maybe something there will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but since calling Navigate there does modify the URL of the page, you could do something like

```
_interval;
doNavigate(){
  ... your call to navigate
  if (this._interval)
    clearInterval(this._interval);
  
  this._interval = setInterval(()=>{
    // check url for what you'd expect when modal closes
    // if url matches, clear interval and run whatever else you want.   
  },1000);
}
```

*edit, make sure to clear interval on disconnectedCallback as well

Comment: P.S. calling clearInterval with an invalid ID is a "no-op", so you don't need to safeguard against it (`if (this._interval)` is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CurrentPageReference` to detect URL changes from `NavigationMixin.Navigate` within your component:

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
```

...

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference) urlUpdated(pageReference) {
  refreshApex(this.wiredData);
}
```

You can inspect the `pageReference` if you want to make sure you're on a specific page, etc. You can read more in [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation).

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I've tried your solution but it's not working for me. I've also updated the question with my full code in order to be more comprehensible. Can you tell me if there's something I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!